# Can we access and replace a image in a xlsx

Tags: python, excel, matplotlib, openpyxl

I am writing a script for automation of a process which requires updating an excel file and then plotting a graph based on some data present in Excel file and then insert the graph in the same Excel file . 
I have used openpyxl for reading and writing excel file and then used matplotlib for drawing a graph for data and then inserted the graph to the same excel file. The data in the Excel file is being updated once or twice a week. Everytime the data is updated I need to plot a updated graph and insert the graph in the Excel file.Right now my script is updating the values in the Excel file Automatically and plotting the graph for the updated data but when I insert the graph it doesnot overwrites the previous graph it everytime appends the graph above the previous graph because of which the size of the Excel file will keep on increasing.

Right now the code that i am using for plotting and inserting the graph in Excel file is-

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,4)) 
PLT = fig.add_axes([0.04, 0.08, 0.79, 0.8]) 

plt.xlabel("WORKING WEEK (WW)",fontsize=7)
plt.ylabel("UTILIZATION [%]",fontsize=7)
plt.title("PATCH UTILIZATION",fontsize=9)
#PLT.subplots_adjust(right=0.8)
for i in range(len(p)):
    PLT.plot(x,p[i],label = '%s'%row[0],marker="s",markersize=2)
PLT.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.21,1),borderaxespad=0,prop={'size':6})
PLT.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=4)
plt.savefig("myplot.png",dpi=160)
wb=load_workbook('Excel.xlsm',read_only=False,keep_vba=True)
ws=wb['Patch Util']
img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image("myplot.png")
img.anchor='D50'
ws.add_image(img)
wb.save('Excel.xlsm')
```

"x" and "p" are two lists (p is list of lists)  which are containing data and will be updated when the data in the Excel file is updated.

What I want is to plot a graph and insert it once. Now whenever the data is updated I want to access the same graph from the Excel file, plot it for updated data and re-inserting it in Excel file,instead of inserting a new graph everytime at the top of previous graph,so that the size of Excel file remains same.

It will be great help if anyone can help me with this

Comment: Relevant: [how-to-find-cells-that-contain-images-with-openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43748023/how-to-find-cells-that-contain-images-with-openpyxl). [Edit] your Question and remove the **whole** `matplot` part, as it's not relevant to your Question.

Comment: Is there no way to access a graph from an excel file(if graph is plotted by matplotlib and then inserted in excel ) as on opening the Excel file by openpyxl graph is not lost - stovfl

Comment: Tried with version **openpyxl:2.4.1** the image are gone! See [Read an existing workbook:Warning](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html?highlight=image#read-an-existing-workbook)

Comment: You keep adding images so what do you expect? It is possible to swap images but this is not documented.

Comment: Yes I know that I am adding images everytimr..that's what i would like to change.Can we access the image inserted in Excel file so that I can update and reinsert it.Please tell me some way or point me to some example if possible.It would be a great help.Thanks...@Charlie Clark

Comment: No..I am using 2.5.6 version and in my case every graph and chart is retained..@stovfl

Comment: Can we delete Images from an Excel file using openpyxl??And if not then how can we swap images as you suggested.Please point me to some example.Thanks. @Charlie Clark

Comment: I said it was **undocumented**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Comment**: No..I am using **2.5.6 version** and in my case every graph and chart is retained

Show me the output of the following:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(<your file path>)
ws = wb.worksheets[<your sheet index>]

for image in ws._images:
    print("_id:{}, img.path:{}".format(image._id, image.path))
```

> **Comment**: the output i got is- `_id:1, img.path:/xl/media/image1.png`

---

> **Question**: Can we access and replace a image in a xlsx

You can do it replacing the `Image object` in `ws._images`.
For the **first time** , you have to initalise the `ref` data, doing it as usual using `ws.add_image(...)`. If an image exists `len(ws._images) == 1` you can replace it with a new `Image object`.
For example:

```
if len(ws._images) == 0:
    # Initalise the `ref` data, do ws.add_image(...)   
    img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image("myplot.png")
    img.anchor='D50'
    ws.add_image(img)

elif len(ws._images) == 1:
    # Replace the first image do **only** the following:
    ws._images[0] = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image("myplot.png")
    # Update the default anchor `A1` to your needs
    ws._images[0].anchor='D50'
else:
    raise(ValueError, "Found more than 1 Image!")
```

> **Note**: You are using a **class private property**, this could result in unexpected side effect.

***Working with openpyxl Version 2.5.6***

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind response. I ran this code and the output i got is-     " _id:1, img.path:/xl/media/image1.png"  @stovfl

Comment: Ohhh ...that is what you wanted....Actually it is showing one graph because right now there is only one graph.The output that i have shown is when there is only one graph actually.When multiple graphs are there then the output that i am getting is -"id:1, img.path:/xl/media/image1.png
_id:1, img.path:/xl/media/image1.png
_id:1, img.path:/xl/media/image1.png
"    and right now there are three graphs when i have checked it manually @stovfl

Comment: Hi now it is updating the previous graph only but the anchor position of the graph is misplaced. Everytime the top left corner of the graph automatically positioned to 'A1' cell of Excel sheet -@stovfl

Comment: Hi now it is working fine.Thank you very much for such a wonderful help. I am highly obliged -@stovfl